# Can you use C# property syntax for vb.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

This is used for C#, but I was wondering if in vb.net you can do the same for quick declaration. such as possibliy

```
public property Name() As String{get; set;}
```

Comment: The parentheses after `Name` say it's an array. I don't think you meant that - just something to watch out for.

Comment: Yes, VB has properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in vb.net

```vb
Public Property Name As String
' in addition, _Name is declared automatically by vb.net
```

but it's not exactly the same as the c#

```cs
public string Name { get; set; }
// _Name is not declared automatically!
```

because the vb.net auto-implemented property creates a backing field automatically called `_Name`, while c# does not.

The expanded property in vb.net is

```vb
Private _Name As String

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

and the c# example is

```cs
private string _Name;

public string Name
{
    get { return _Name; }
    set { _Name = value; }
}
```

The properties are equivalent when the properties are expanded and backing fields are explicitly declared.

I would avoid accessing the auto-implemented backing field in vb.net, however, because it could lead to confusion since its declaration is invisible.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Public Property Name As String
```

ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Comment: Might want to add the actual get/set code to the example as a better reference, but the link spells it out pretty well.

Comment: @user2366842 As an auto-implemented property, the get/set is not required.